# C# getting an error. Cannot implicity convert from System.Data.DataRow to DataRow

Tags: c#, implicit, datarow

I am getting this error

```
"Error  8   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataRow>'
```

"

I line of code that is generating the problem is this...

```
List<DataRow> dRowList = target.SearchFor(searchPhrase, searchField, matchesAny);
```

target.SearchFor return a DataRow list. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you add the signature for `SearchFor` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
var dRowList = target.SearchFor(searchPhrase, searchField, matchesAny);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I still don't quite get what the problem was but it does work now.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List<System.Data.DataRow> dRowList = target.SearchFor(searchPhrase, searchField, matchesAny);
```

I assume that you defined another type named `DataRow`, right? If so, you must explicitly write which one you want to use.

Comment: I like your thinking. I tried this but, for whatever reason, it didn't work.